# Problem inserting a user variable in connection expression

Tags: ssis, scope, foreach-loop-container

I am trying to import 110 excel files into a sql server database in SSIS2008.

I am at the the point where I have dragged in my foreach loop container, pointed to the correct folder. I have made a string variable (with foreach loop scope) and set the default value to a file in the source folder of excel files.

When I try to build a connection string expression and try to find the user variable it is not in the list. The only variables in the list are system variables.

Does anyone have any idea where I might be going wrong. I feel that I have set the correct scope by defining the string variable from the foreach loop.

(The User::FilePath variable that I made is not visible in the package explorer either.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I find I generally have a better SSIS experience when I keep my variables at the package level.  I suspect the connection manager doesn't like the connection string variable only being visible in the loop and that may be causing it some heartache for design-time validation.  The user variable(s) you've created are visible, just not visible at the scope you're looking at.  If you've clicked on the canvas/background of SSIS, you'll only see package level variables.  My suspicion is the variables are in the foreach loop or possibly even on the dataflow or other tasks within the foreach container.

If you really want to find where you created those variables, look at the unused tab "Package Explorer".  Keep expanding Executables and looking at the Variables item until you find your missing variables.

Finally, if you have variables at the "wrong" level, user [BIDS Helper](http://bidshelper.codeplex.com/).  Even if you have the variables at the right level, grab BIDS Helper.  It's free and it really improves the package development experience.